# How can I color code a graph in Excel using VBA, using the RGB mix?

Tags: vba, excel, colors

I would like to use VBA to modify the color in a graph/chart in Excel based on values in 3 cells (correlated to RGB).

For example, cells A1 (Red), A2 (Green), and A3 (Blue) would each have a value that would correspond to a certain color. Based upon those values, the bar graph color would change to whatever the RGB color indicated. 115-20-110 would give me a pink bar color.

I currently have

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Interior.Color = RGB(A1, A2, A3)
```

But I don't really know VBA and it isn't working. Any help is appreciated, and if there is a less obtuse way I would be interested of course.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Interior.Color = RGB(Range("A1").Value, _
                                                       Range("A2").Value, _
                                                       Range("A3").Value)
```

`SeriesCollection` represents all of the series on the chart - you need to pick one to color...

Comment: Thanks very much. This worked great. I didn't understand the series part of it